# Consume .NET WebService - Parsing an array of data from an asmx WebService in Android

Tags: android, web-services, xml-parsing, asmx, android-parser

I have a .NET Web-services with asmx extension.
The service http://www.web.com/SampleService/SampleService.asmx has two endpoints:

First is http://www.web.com/SampleService/SampleService.asmx/GetName
which provides the name of the customers in the following format:
[image]

Similarly, the second endpoint http://www.web.com/SampleService/SampleService.asmx/GetTax also returns some XML data.

I want to parse both of those xml data from the link http://www.web.com/SampleService/SampleService.asmx

I have read [this](http://translate.google.com.ua/translate?hl=uk&sl=ru&tl=en&u=http://mobile-developer.ru/uncategorized/rabota-s-soap-web-servisami-v-android-prilozheniyax/) tutorial which describes how to consume Web-services applications in the Android by using `kSOAP2 - library`. But in this tutorial, they explained how to pass the data to web and make some adding operation. But I need to parse the xml data from asmx link given above, and update the results to a `ListView`. How can I do this? Please anyone help me with a full example?

Comment: Consuming ASMX WebServices using kSOAP2 is a lot of work. If you are in control of the WebServices, you might consider changing it to A REST/JSON API. It'll be fairly easy to consume it in Android. IF you have the control, AND time to change the services

Comment: @RenanMalkeStigliani I'll consider your suggestion.. thank you..

Answer (score 2):

```
private static void parseResponse(InputStream is, SoapEnvelope envelope)
          throws Throwable {
        try {
          XmlPullParser xp = new KXmlParser();
          xp.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, true);                          

          xp.setInput(is, "UTF-8"); //UTF-8

          envelope.parse(xp);
        } catch (Throwable e) {           
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error reading/parsing SOAP response", e);
            throw e;
        }
      }
```

....

```
parseResponse(is, envelope);
Object bodyIn = envelope.bodyIn;            
        if (bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) {
            throw (SoapFault) bodyIn;
        }
```

where `is` is the input stream from your web request. If parsing is ok, the bodyIn will contain `SoapObject`